# Multiple git remotes handling

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a project hosted on github and bitbucket using git.
Simply put this project is a cap+puppet+vagrant deployment strategy.
The git repository is handled by a consultant which is occasionnaly working on it.

The thing is: in my bitbucket repo, i only wish to only keep the puppet files because i already have a global cap project handling multiple applications on a separate repo.

So my question: can and how can i ignore files for one remote whilst keeping them in the other.
The point to this is that i want my consultant to be able to keep commit/pushing changes in his git repo to have the bb repo up-to-date, but completely ignore any cap config/modifications from the git repo on the bb repo.

Thanks much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git ignore files per branch or remote repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334400/git-ignore-files-per-branch-or-remote-repository)

Comment: I confirm this is a duplicate, thanks for pointing out. apparently what i want to achieve is impossible.